# regular expression matching fully qualified java variable

Tags: java, regex

Is there any regular expression to match the fully qualified java variables?

For ex: to get the variable name from the following example line.

```
public static final ByteOrder BIG_ENDIAN = ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN;
  ByteOrder order = null;
```

Comment: Actually I have tried with getting the methods from a java files. /(public|protected|private|static|\s)+[\w\<\>\[\]]+\s+(\w+) *\([^\)]*\) *(\{?|[^;])*/   I am getting the methods in a java file. Same as I need to get the variables.

Comment: I think the pattern will be simlar to that.

Comment: *Which* variable name? There are three in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String z = "public static final ByteOrder BIG_ENDIAN = ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN;\nByteOrder order = null;";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^ =]+[ ]*=[^=]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(z);
while (matcher.find()) {
    String match = matcher.group();
    match = match.substring(0, match.length()-2).trim();
    System.out.println(match);
}
```

Will match any assignment.

Comment: Yes That was worked Thanks. BUt if the variable is not assigned then i am getting the problem. I mean for the example varaiable lines like:     int age; public static final ByteOrder;                                                I mean I need not only assigned variables but also the non assigned variables too.